# CSS-animation starting on JS-event, using variable colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, css-animations

I have a table of cells and whenever I click one I want it to start flashing a color indicating it is selected and stop others from flashing, thus deselecting them (so only one is cell selected at a time). I also want the cell to "remember" what its former color was, so it flashes between it's old color and the new "select color".

The problems are:

1. I don't know how to make the deselection. *Done!*
2. It doesn't remember the old color, which in this case is red, but it could be anything (it's depending on a variable) *Still in progress*

**UPDATE:** Thank you for your answers, I have used some of your methods but I haven't yet fully covered my objectives. This is what I have now: https://jsfiddle.net/t3g3mq02/12

The problem I still have is that **the CSS animation doesn't change if JS changes the regular background color**, as it seems like it inherits the color from CSS. In the final code I have functions that change the background color and I simulated this in the sample code with this line: `tds[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";`. I added it into the iteration, just as an example.

The solution could be something like changing the animation's style with JS, but I don't know how to do that.

HTML:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i=0; i<tds.length; i++) {
    tds[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    tds[i].onclick = function() {
        var selected = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
        if(selected.length > 0)
            selected[0].className = "";
        this.className = "selected";
    };
}
```

CSS:

```
tr {
    background: red
}

.selected {
    animation: colorchange 1.5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: colorchange 1.5s infinite;
}

@keyframes colorchange
{
    0%, 100%   {background: inherit;}
    40%  {background: cyan;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorchange /* Safari and Chrome - necessary duplicate */
{
    0%, 100%   {background: inherit;}
    40%  {background: cyan;}
}
```

Feel free to scrap my code and propose a whole new approach!

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
   <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td class='cell-color'>Jill</td>
            <td class='cell-color'>Smith</td> 
            <td class='cell-color'>50</td>
        </tr>
```

Changes: removed all javascript from html. Gave the cells a class name for selection.

Javascript:

```
(function(){
    var cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell-color')

    for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
        cells[i].addEventListener('click', changeColor, false);
    }

})();

function changeColor(cell){
    var old = document.querySelector('.selected');
    old.className = 'cell';

    var cell = cell.targetElement.src;

    cell.className += 'selected';
}
```

Here I select all the cells by their class name add an `eventListener` to each cell, remove the old selected class and add a new selected class.

Css:

```
tr {
    background-color: red;
}

@keyframes colorchange
{
    0%, 100%   {background: inherit;}
    40%  {background: cyan;}
}
```

Changes: Use inherit from `tr` so you don't have to use complicated javascript dom css api to change the value inside the `keyframe`.

and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3g3mq02/11/);

Comment: Hi, do you have any solution for the problem I stated in comments under @LcSalazar ? https://jsfiddle.net/t3g3mq02/12/ the animation doesn't know if the color has been changed by JS.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier if you don't use a table.

What you can do instead is a set of `<label>` elements. Something like this...

```css
.row {
  display: block;
}
.row>input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
.row>div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.row>input:checked~div {
  background-color: #fcc;
}
```

```html
<label class="row">
  <input type="radio" name="rowselect" value="1" />
  <div>Option 1</div>
</label>
<label class="row">
  <input type="radio" name="rowselect" value="2" />
  <div>Option 2</div>
</label>
<label class="row">
  <input type="radio" name="rowselect" value="3" />
  <div>Option 3</div>
</label>
```

You can of course adjust as needed, and use different style methods to get a table-like appearance.

Comment: I like how you right away thought about radio buttons, I made a fiddle for him with his structure. https://jsfiddle.net/t3g3mq02/7/

Answer (score 1):

You should rethink this approach, as there are easier ways to accomplish it. But just to follow your current work, I've made a few adjustments on your fiddle:

[**UPDATED JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/t3g3mq02/9/)

> *1. I don't know how to make the deselection.*

Remove your inline `onclick` handler, and place a script that assigns a click handler to each td. On the handling function, look for another `.selected` element and remove the class from it, before you assign it to the clicked element:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i=0; i<tds.length; i++) {
    tds[i].onclick = function() {
        var selected = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
        if(selected.length > 0)
            selected[0].className = "";
        this.className = "selected";
    };
}
```

> *2. It doesn't remember the old color, which in this case is red, but it could be anything (it's depending on a variable)*

Instead of assigning a color to the `td`, set the color to the `tr`. Then, alternate between the color you want blinking (cyan) and the `inherit` property value.

```
tr {
    background: red
}

@keyframes colorchange
{
    0%, 100%   {background: inherit;}
    40%  {background: cyan;}
}
```

Comment: This and @ryan's were the only ones that did exactly what I wanted (at least straight out of the box), but second problem isn't yet fully covered, as the background color might change in JS and seems like `inherit` inherits the color from CSS. I made an example to show what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/t3g3mq02/12/ . I added a line: `tds[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";` into the iteration, just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Although I really like Niet's use of radio buttons, I will still add my fiddle since it keeps your structure:
https://jsfiddle.net/t3g3mq02/7/

```
<table id="mainTable" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
var table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
table.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var selected = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
    if(selected.length > 0){
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(selected,function(element, index, array){
            element.classList.remove("selected");
        });
    }
    e.target.classList.add("selected");
}, false);
```